Table Question: How do I stop the color in a cell from blocking a cline?
I have a table with four columns that group into two larger columns. I am using the package tabularx. When I input \cline{2-5} to place a line above those columns, it is visible when the table is without color, but the color in the cell hides it once present. I have viewed many posts on the issue, but have found most posts to concern this issue deeper within a table and not at the very beginning of a table and could not rig examples to fix my issue. I appreciate any feedback and pro-tips. Below is a working example of my code.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,0.98,0.46}
\usepackage{multirow, hhline}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |l| *{4}{Y|} }
\cline{2-5}

   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} 
 \rowcolor{Gray}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Number of Dogs}}  
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Dogs Per Household}}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
 \textbf{Group and Home} & \textbf{2022} & \textbf{2023} & \textbf{2022} & \textbf{2023} \\
\hline
 {\cellcolor{yellow}1}  & 2 &  2 &  1.24 & 1.42 \\ \hline
 {\cellcolor{yellow}2}  &  5 & 45 &  1.15 &  1.13 \\ \hline
 {\cellcolor{yellow}3}  &  3 & 3 & 1.03 &  1.01 \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{document}


Here is a photo. You will see the top line above columns 2-5 is absent: 

see the colortbl manual,  \cline is explicitly not supported.  You could use hhline but using rules and coloured panels isn't really necessary I would drop all the horizontal and vertical rules

To elaborate on @DavidCarlisle's suggestion: Do consider getting rid of all vertical and horizontal rules in this small table. If you feel it's absolutely essential to provide a vertical rule along the right-hand edge and a horizontal rule along the bottom edge, you could use an \arrayrulecolor directive to render these rules in Gray and thus much less prominent, visually speaking.
Also, since you're using colors as a prominent highlighting device, you could get rid of the \textbf directives in the header. For sure, please avoid mixing-and-mismatching visual metaphores.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,0.98,0.46}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{Gray}
\noindent % <-- don't forget this directive
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l CCCC |}  
\rowcolor{Gray}
Group and Home & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Number of Dogs} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Dogs Per Household}\\

\rowcolor{Gray}
& 2022 & 2023 & 2022 & 2023 \\

\cellcolor{yellow} 1 & 2 &  2 & 1.24 & 1.42 \\
\cellcolor{yellow} 2 & 5 & 45 & 1.15 & 1.13 \\ 
\cellcolor{yellow} 3 & 3 &  3 & 1.03 & 1.01 \\ 
\cline{2-5}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}


With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\columncolor{yellow!50}}l*{4}{X[c]}}[hvlines,corners]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,rowcolor=gray!15]{\bfseries}
 & \Block{1-2}{Number of Dogs}  
 && \Block{1-2}{Dogs Per Household} \\
 Group and Home & 2022 & 2023 & 2022  &  2023  \\
             1  &  2   &  2   &  1.24  & 1.42  \\ 
             2  &  5   & 45   &   1.15 &  1.13 \\ 
             3  &  3   & 3    &  1.03  &  1.01 \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}

You need several compilations.


As suggested in comments, use \hhline.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,0.98,0.46}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |l| *{4}{Y|} }
\hhline{~|-|-|-|-|}
\rowcolor{Gray}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{white}} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Number of Dogs}}  
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Dogs Per Household}}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
\textbf{Group and Home} & \textbf{2022} & \textbf{2023} & \textbf{2022} & \textbf{2023} \\
\hline
\cellcolor{yellow}1 & 2 &  2 & 1.24 & 1.42 \\ \hline
\cellcolor{yellow}2 & 5 & 45 & 1.15 & 1.13 \\ \hline
\cellcolor{yellow}3 & 3 &  3 & 1.03 & 1.01 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{A colorful table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l c c c c}
\toprule
Groups and Home &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Number of Dogs} \\
\cmidrule{2-5}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Absolute} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makebox[0pt]{per Household}} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5}
& 2022 & 2023 & 2022 & 2023 \\
\midrule
1  & 2 &  2 & 1.24 & 1.42 \\
2  & 5 & 45 & 1.15 & 1.13 \\
3  & 3 &  3 & 1.03 & 1.01 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{A less fanciful table}

\end{table}

\end{document}

Note that \rowcolor should go before \multicolumn.
I also propose, as you see, a less fanciful realization. The only trick is the zero-width box in order to avoid the excess width to go in the last column.

A final comment: the code
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

is exactly the same as
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

